# Thunar keyboard shortcut to change tab

Tags: gtk, thunar

Currently in Thunar, to shift to the next tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> is to be used. I want to change it to either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

Now, `~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm` is where all the shortcuts are defined in this format :

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/new-tab" "<Primary>t")
```

My question is:

1. what is the keyword for changing tab that should replace `new-tab` in the above example?
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> -> `<Primary>`. So how about <kbd>Tab</kbd> -> ? and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> -> ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thunar doesn't actually have a keybinding for changing to the next/previous tab, but instead the underlying GTK control, in this case GtkNotebook, has some key bindings.

GtkNotebook defines previous tab as both `Ctrl`+`PageUp` and `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`PageUp` (and similarly for next tab/page down); however, in Thunar's case, the `Ctrl`+`PageUp`/`Ctrl`+`PageDown` keybinding is blocked by the fact that the pane you're viewing (the icon and details view) is of type GtkScrolledWindow and has its own usage of `Ctrl`+`PageUp`/`Ctrl`+`PageDown` decribed here:
https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/2.24/class-gtkscrolledwindow.html#signal-gtkscrolledwindow--scroll-child

The last time I installed an OS with Thunar on it, it didn't even have tabs so I immediately discarded it and used PCManFM, which although it doesn't define a next/previous tab key, doesn't use a GtkScrolledWindow for the viewing of the files and therefore the built-in `Ctrl`+`PageUp`/`Ctrl`+`PageDown` for the tab widget works.

IMO both programs (and all file managers) should define these, and use reasonable defaults, in addition to supporting move tab left/right like many browsers do (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`PageUp`/`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`PageDown`).

For Thunar, I have a patch I made to at least define all 4 of these events as keybinds explicitly (which would make them overrideable in the way you described in your original post) that I hope to post soon in this bug report:
https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9585

Unfortunately while it does let you change the keybinds for those events, it doesn't let you override existing keybinds from child widgets (such as GtkScrolledWindow), so you'd have to use and bind something like `Alt`+`PageUp`/`Alt`+`PageDown` or equally messy.  If I figure out a patch for that, I'll definitely post it to the bug, but that's proving harder to figure out.

*** **Edit** ***

You can move to a specific tab using `Alt`+`N`, where `N` is a number `0-9`, but I find this to be of very limited use.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. Any chance I can have a peak at that patch? :D

Comment: There's now a [bounty on Bountysource](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/3547148-keyboard-shortcuts-for-tab-navigation) for this problem.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`PageUp` and `Ctrl`+`PageDown` seem to work now

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey).

Create two new AutoKey scripts with the Window filter: **thunar.Thunar**

1. Assign Ctrl-Tab to this script code:

   ```
   keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<alt>+<page_down>")
   ```
2. Assign Ctrl-Shift-Tab to this script code:

   ```
   keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<alt>+<page_up>")
   ```